# How to verify Async request in PHP guzzle?

Tags: php, laravel, promise, guzzle

I have this `getAsync()` in my `HTTP` class

```
public static function getAsync($urls) {

    try {
        $client = new Client();
        $options = [
            'http_errors' => false,
            'connect_timeout' => 3.14,
            'read_timeout' => 3.14,
            'timeout' => 3.14,
            'verify' => false,

        ];

        $headers = [
            'headers' => [
                'Keep-Alive' => 'timeout=300'
            ]
        ];

        foreach ($urls as $name => $url) {
            $promises[$name] = $client->requestAsync('GET', $url, $headers, $options);
        }

        $results = Promise\settle($promises)->wait();

        $array = [];

        foreach ($results as $name => $data) {
            if ($data['state'] === 'fulfilled') {
                $array[$name] = json_decode($data['value']->getBody()->getContents(),TRUE);
            } else {
                return $data['reason'];
            }
        }

        return $array;

    } catch (ConnectException $e) {

        //Logging::error($e);

        return null;
    }

}
```

In my controller, I did

```
$cpeCountUrl          = $ip.':'.$port.'/devices/all.count';
$deviceCountUrl       = $ip.':'.$port.'/devices/all.count';
$nodeRegistrationsUrl = $ip.':'.$port.'/registrations';

$promises                      = [];
$promises['cpeCount']          = $cpeCountUrl;
$promises['deviceCount']       = $deviceCountUrl;
$promises['nodeRegistrations'] = $nodeRegistrationsUrl;

$responses = HTTP::getAsync($promises);

//dd($responses);

$cpeCount          = $responses['cpeCount']['data']['Count_of_devices'];
$deviceCount       = $responses['deviceCount']['data'];
$totalDeviceCount  = $deviceCount['Count_of_devices'];
$activeDeviceCount = $deviceCount['Count_of_active'];
```

Everything is working perfectly fine as expected, how do I test or prove that my 3 requests now are kicking off at the same time?

Is there a `tool`, `site`, `app` that I can use to test or verify `requestAsync()` in Guzzle?

Comment: If you don't have insight on the server side you could use a packet analyzer like WireShark. You are clear that PHP is still not multi-threaded and Guzzle is, I assume, using asynchronous cURL functions?

Comment: I'm trying to look over, in the meantime look over this repo to make concurrent request https://github.com/elminson/MultiProccessingCurlRequests

Comment: curl_multi will fire off a stack of requests. PHP can't run in parallel though. Things will block until the curl handle completes the stack of requests. Might not be what you expected if coming from another language that is multi threaded.